# How to set seed dynamically for LLVM Random Number Generator?

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

According to the doc [llvm random number generator](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1RandomNumberGenerator.html), it says

> The seed should be set by passing the -rng-seed= option.

So this is a static parameter?

Can I have something like C's `srand(seed)`? That is using a runtime value to initialize a random number generator in LLVM?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there's no alternative and you need to use the `-rng-seed` option if you want to set the seed. The seed value is global static in [this](http://llvm.org/doxygen/RandomNumberGenerator_8cpp_source.html) compilation unit, so it'll be always overridden by the command-line option.

Maybe you can emulate the random seed generation using `/dev/urandom` with something like this with above command-line option (especially if you wrap the pass invocation in a script):

```
head -100 /dev/urandom | cksum | awk '{print $1}'
```

This will allow you to keep the flexibility of having the same pseudo-random sequence generated for debugging purposes, without having to recompile.